# Using JSON.NET to return ActionResult

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to write a C# method that will serialize a model and return a JSON result.  Here's my code:

```
    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var items = db.Words.Take(1).ToList();
        JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        var converted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, null, jsSettings);
        return Json(converted, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I got the following JSON result when I go to Words/Read in Chrome:

```
"[{\"WordId\":1,\"Rank\":1,\"PartOfSpeech\":\"article\",\"Image\":\"Upload/29/1/Capture1.PNG\",\"FrequencyNumber\":\"22038615\",\"Article\":null,\"ClarificationText\":null,\"WordName\":\"the | article\",\"MasterId\":0,\"SoundFileUrl\":\"/UploadSound/7fd752a6-97ef-4a99-b324-a160295b8ac4/1/sixty_vocab_click_button.mp3\",\"LangId\":1,\"CatId\":null,\"IsActive\":false}
```

I think the \" escaped quotes are a problem that occurs when you double serialize an object.  From other questions:
[WCF JSON output is getting unwanted quotes & backslashes added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294473/wcf-json-output-is-getting-unwanted-quotes-backslashes-added)

It definitely looks like I'm double serializing my object, since I first serialize using JSON.NET and then pass my result into the Json() function.  I need to manually serialize to avoid referenceloops, but I think my View needs an ActionResult.

How can I return an ActionResult here?  Do I need to, or can I just return a string?

Comment: On the javascript return I just do JSON.parse(message);.

Comment: You mean using Javascript to just parse out the /"s?  I'm using Razor HTML helpers for a specific package, so I don't know how I would get that to work..

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I found a similar stackoverflow question:
[Json.Net And ActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938907/json-net-and-actionresult)

The answer there suggested using

```
return Content( converted, "application/json" );
```

That seems to work on my very simple page.

Comment: IMO best answer. Simple and does exactly what was asked.

Comment: if you will check the headers, you will see you probably have `text/html` as content type.

Comment: By far the simplest solution. This does exactly what it needs to.

Comment: Based on hubatish's answer:
<code>
public abstract class ControllerBase : Controller
    {
        protected const string JsonEncoding = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        protected ContentResult JsonNetResult(object result)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
            return Content(json, JsonEncoding);
        }
    }
</code>

Comment: @Dementic Maybe something has changed in 4 years but using the syntax in this answer my response headers show `content-type: application/json`.

Answer (score 69):

Instead of serializing using JSON.NET and then calling `Json()`, why not instead override the `Json()` method in your controller (or perhaps a base controller to enhance its re-usability)?

This is pulled from this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20150506070012/http://wingkaiwan.com:80/2012/12/28/replacing-mvc-javascriptserializer-with-json-net-jsonserializer/).

In your controller (or base controller):

```
protected override JsonResult Json(
        object data,
        string contentType,
        System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding,
        JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
{
    return new JsonNetResult
    {
        Data = data,
        ContentType = contentType,
        ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
        JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
    };
}
```

And the definition for JsonNetResult:

```
public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        };
    }

    public JsonSerializerSettings Settings { get; private set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    if (this.JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
        && "GET".Equals(
                context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("JSON GET is not allowed");
    }


        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType =
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType) ? "application/json" : this.ContentType;

        if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
        if (this.Data == null)
            return;

        var scriptSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(this.Settings);

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            scriptSerializer.Serialize(sw, this.Data);
            response.Write(sw.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this, when you call `Json()` in your controller, you will automatically get the JSON.NET serializing you want.

Comment: Cool.  This is pretty convenient.  Also, I was thinking this would allow me to still pass JSONRequestBehavior.AllowGet, but it doesn't quite seem to be working.

Comment: To get that to work, you'd need to add overrides to `Json()` that pass in default values for the other parameters. This is what the default implementation does.

Comment: Well, this line 

    Json(object data, string contentType, System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)

seems to mean I can do Json(converted,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); but I get "To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet." when I go to the page.

Comment: Just pass in null for `contentType` and `contentEncoding` and you'll get the same results as the default implementation. Otherwise add an overload to `Json()` that only takes `data` and `behavior`, and provide null values for `contentType` and `contentEncoding`, and then call the implementation with all parameters I have in my answer.

Comment: The answer by @hubatish himself is better.

Comment: The JsonNetResult's enforcement of AllowGet seems redundant with the attributes applied to the mehtod - it surprised me that I had to redundantly enable AllowGet when I already have AcceptVerbsAttribute.  Need to find out how to read AcceptVerbsAttribute from the ControllerContext.

Comment: Great response. My question is in regards to the very last part: is it better to serialize everything to a StringWriter and then write to the HTTP response, or would writing directly to the output stream be more efficient?  `using (var sw = new StreamWriter(response.OutputStream, response.ContentEncoding)) {
                scriptSerializer.Serialize(sw, Data);
                sw.Flush();
            }`