# Unable to Serialize/Deserialize List<> object into JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am working on 2 web applications; A & B. now i have a shared class named CRUDOutput as follow on both web applications:-

```
public class CRUDOutput
{
    public Operation4 operation { get; set; }
}
public class Operation4
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Result
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }

}
```

now inside web application A i am returning the following:-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateResource(CreateResource cr)
{
    List<CRUDOutput> co = new List<CRUDOutput>();
            co.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CRUDOutput>(crudoutput));
            co.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CRUDOutput>(crudoutput2));

    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(co));
}
```

now from web application B, i am calling the action method as follow:-

```
try
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) 
    {
        string url = "https://localhost:44302/" + "Home/CreateResource";
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");

        output = wc.UploadString(uri,  data);
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
}
List<CRUDOutput> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List< CRUDOutput>>(output);
```

but i will get the following exception when i tried to deserialize the output:-

> Error converting value
>   "[{"operation":{"result":{"status":"Success","message":"Resource has
>   been added successfully to ......"},"name":"CREATE
>   RESOURCE"}},{"operation":{"result":{"status":"Failed","message":"Account
>   addition "},"name":"ADD ACCOUNTS"}}]" to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[S.ViewModels.CRUDOutput]'. Path '',
>   line 1, position 464.

now the JSON return from web application A will be as follow:-

```
"\"[{\\\"operation\\\":{\\\"result\\\":{\\\"status\\\":\\\"Success\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Resource 123 rfrf has been added successfully \\\"},\\\"name\\\":\\\"CREATE RESOURCE\\\"}},{\\\"operation\\\":{\\\"result\\\":{\\\"status\\\":\\\"Failed\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Account addition \\\"},\\\"name\\\":\\\"ADD ACCOUNTS\\\"}}]\""
```

so can anyone advice why i am unable to deserialize to a list of objects?

Comment: what is `result` in the controller method?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh sorry i miss type it ,,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output as you've pasted is encoded as JSON twice.  Compare the difference between:

```
"\"[{\\\"operation\\\":{\\\"result\\\":{\\\"status\\\":\\\"Success\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Resource 123 rfrf has been added successfully \\\"},\\\"name\\\":\\\"CREATE RESOURCE\\\"}},{\\\"operation\\\":{\\\"result\\\":{\\\"status\\\":\\\"Failed\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Account addition \\\"},\\\"name\\\":\\\"ADD ACCOUNTS\\\"}}]\""
```

and

```
"[{\"operation\":{\"result\":{\"status\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"Resource 123 rfrf has been added successfully \"},\"name\":\"CREATE RESOURCE\"}},{\"operation\":{\"result\":{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"message\":\"Account addition \"},\"name\":\"ADD ACCOUNTS\"}}]"
```

This happens because you're encoding the result as Json twice.  Replace:

```
return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

with

```
return Json(result);    // This encodes as JSON automatically
```

Comment: so you mean MVC will do the serialization for me ?

Comment: Yes, it will.  The `Json` method takes an object, not a string.

Comment: so will there be any benefit of using JSON.net ? as seems mvc will do the job out of the box? or JSON.net will do things which MVC can not do out of the box ?

Comment: MVC uses json.net under the covers.

Comment: @Richard This is a common point of confusion.  ASP.NET MVC actually does *not* use Json.Net under the covers; it uses JavaScriptSerializer, apparently for backward compatibility reasons.  (See the source code for [JsonResult](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonResult.cs).)  ASP.NET Web API on the other hand, *does* use Json.Net.  To get MVC to also use Json.Net, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348262/using-json-net-to-return-actionresult).

Comment: @BrianRogers so in my case if i want to return an object using JavaScriptSerializer from my action method what are the approaches i can follow?

Comment: @johng If you want to use `JavaScriptSerializer`, then just use `Json(result)` as Richard showed you in his answer above.

Comment: @BrianRogers sorry i meant if i want to return Json.Net from my action method ..how i can do so ? second point will the returned json differ if i serialize it using json.net or javascriptserializer ? i think both will/should just serialize exactly the same json object... i mean since i am deserializing using json.net ,,, will it cause any problem if i serialize using other library or just say return Json(result)

Comment: @johnG 1. To use Json.Net in MVC there are two approaches; both are covered here: [Using JSON.NET to return ActionResult](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23348262/10263).  2. The two serializers are mostly interoperable, but there are some differences.  The biggest difference is how they treat dates.  JavaScriptSerializer serializes dates like `"\/Date(1465582440724)\/"`, whereas Json.Net serializes them like `"2016-06-10T13:14:00.724082-05:00"` by default.  Json.Net does have a `DateFormatHandling` setting that allows it to use the JavaScriptSerializer format though, if you need to.