# Return JavaScript object literal, not JSON string, from ASP.NET MVC endpoint

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

For various reasons, I have switched from ASP.NET MVC's built in JSON serializer (<s>the one that returns a `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` object</s> *(see edit below)*) to Newtonsoft. I didn't realize until after I began testing that the former returns a JavaScript object literal, while Newtonsoft returns a JSON formatted *string*.

I like not having to parse JSON strings on the client side — having it already as an object literal is very convenient — but I want to stick with Newtonsoft for other technical reasons.

For example, instead of seeing this result on my client...

```
"{"Errors":["Please enter a valid email address."],"HasErrors":true}"
```

...I'd like to see this result:

```
{"Errors":["Please enter a valid email address."],"HasErrors":true} // no quotes
```

Is there a way to make Newtonsoft return JS object literals instead of strings?

## EDIT

The way my question was framed wasn't the best. There's nothing wrong with the `JsonResult` type. In fact, the solution still uses it. The only problem was the default `Controller.Json` methods, which can be overridden to use Newtonsoft (Json.NET) instead of the built-in serializer.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the .NET world - is Newtonsoft on the server? Because if so, you should never be able to return a JS literal at from the server. Not in a network request, anyway. Or is that embedded somewhere in the page when it renders?

Comment: Can't you edit your JS file with a JSON.Parse(response) ?

Comment: How are you creating your JSON responses and returning them from MVC using Json.Net?

Comment: @vlaz Yes, Newtonsoft is a small framework for .NET that handles everything "JSON". It sure seems like they're coming over as JS literals -- they even have a MIME type of `application/json`. But the way it's currently doing it with Newtonsoft, they're coming over as JSON strings with a MIME type of `text/html`.

Comment: @BrianRogers when I was using MVC's built in serializer and getting the desired result, my endpoint would have something like `return Json(returnObject)` with a return type of `JsonResult`. With Newtonsoft, it looks like `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnObject)` with a return type of `string`.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using to plug in Json.NET?  Is it similar to [Using JSON.NET to return ActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348262/using-json-net-to-return-actionresult) or [Using JSON.NET as the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC 3 - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109967)?  Json.NET doesn't serialize objects by surrounding them with quotes so likely something is going wrong with how Json.NET is being plugged in.

Comment: @dbc I doubt it's an implementation problem. I started a basic MVC 5 project in Visual Studio, then simply downloaded the Newtonsoft NuGet package. I haven't tinkered with anything -- it's all out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a custom JsonResult that uses Newtonsoft serializer:

Something along the lines:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult
        {
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
            Data = data
        };
    }

    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult
                    {
                        ContentType = contentType,
                        ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
                        Data = data,
                        JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
                    };
    }
}
```

JsonNetResult.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{   
    public JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings { get; set; }
    public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }

    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.None;
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        if (JsonRequestBehavior == JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
            && String.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType)
                                    ? ContentType
                                    : "application/json";

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

        if (Data != null)
        {
            var writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting };

            var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(SerializerSettings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, Data);

            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Credit: https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/1424538

Comment: This is perfect! I ended up implementing an even simpler version of this by using `response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Data))` instead of the `JsonTextWriter` and `JsonSerializer`. I'll never need to use any special `JsonSerializerSettings` or `Formatting`, and working with writers always strikes me as overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here: [How to force ASP.NET Web API to always return JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629144/how-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-always-return-json)

Excerpt:

Clear all formatters and add Json formatter back.

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
EDIT

I added it to Global.asax inside Application_Start().

Comment: I am not using Web API. The endpoints on my controller include ViewResults, Json strings, and file results as well, so I don't think this would work for me.